# Mule VM - data loss / Not processing all data in the VM

Tags: multithreading, virtual-machine, mule, endpointbehavior

Mule 3.4 is creating only the default 16 threads and didn't take any configurations specified in my code below.

1. MaxActive="100" is not created, it just creates 16 threads and process them.
2. INITIALISE_ALL is also not working, it is having one idle thread and when data is submitted, then it creates the 16 and do the process. so, MaxIdle=2 is also not working
   (Monitored using jvisualvm)

Why does it not override the default behavior? Am I missing something?

The most critical issue, I face now is, when I submit some 28 ids to the VM, it process some of them, and there is no clue about the remaining and there is no specific number / pattern for this. (I'm unable to replicate the issue in my local box, this is happening in higher env like QA, UAT boxes and it was working without this issue as mentioned above before). Please help.

```
<flow name="Event0">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint ref="PROCESS.EVENT0" />
    <pooled-component>
        <spring-object bean="abcProcess" />
        <pooling-profile exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_WAIT" initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ALL" maxActive="100" maxIdle="2"    maxWait="20000" />
    </pooled-component>
    <custom-exception-strategy class="org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy">
        <commit-transaction exception-pattern="*" />
        <vm:outbound-endpoint ref="ErrorHandlerInput" />
    </custom-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: The definition of `PROCESS.EVENT0` is not shown so we don't know if it's `one-way` or request response. Also you don't show how you've configured the threading profiles. Very hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy`, and the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current/apidocs/org/mule/exception/DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy.html) says:

> This is the default exception handler for flows and services. The
>   handler logs errors and will forward the message and exception to an
>   exception endpoint if one is set on this Exception strategy. If an
>   endpoint is configured via the element, a Dead Letter Queue pattern is
>   assumed and so the transaction will commit. Otherwise, the transaction
>   will rollback, possibly causing the source message to be redelivered
>   (depends on the transport).

So you should probably check the logs and the exception endpoint you seem to have configured.